# How do I find the name of this control? "Cannot read property 'focus' of null"

Tags: html, whatsapp

I am trying to focus an element of web.whatsapp.com.

I use "Inspect" in Chrome to find its name.
As I read it, the name is

```
div.Er7QU.copyable-text selectable-text"
```

However, when I call ".focus()" on it...

```
document.querySelector("div.Er7QU.copyable-text selectable-text").focus();
```

I receive the error

```
Cannot read property 'focus' of null.
```

What am I doing wrong?

In Chrome, it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must use `document.querySelector("div.Er7QU.copyable-text.selectable-text").focus();`

You need to concatenate all class names via the . (also, this is exactly what appears on your screenshot. There are no spaces between the classes)

Also, as `@Rick` mentioned, make sure to protect the code by using a conditional statement that will check whether the selector returned null before running any methods on the element selected.

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector("div.Er7QU.copyable-text selectable-text") is returning null. code it like this to avoid errors, but something else is wrong with your code:

```js
var el = document.querySelector("div.Er7QU.copyable-text selectable-text");
if (el) 
{
  el.focus();
}
else
{
    alert('Element not found.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The error is indeed that the element is not found.

Comment: It is not found because of the wrong selector value @tmighty. Check my answer for using the correct selector.